# @Async with CompletableFuture#get not throws custom RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, completable-future, spring-async

I have this method:

```
@Async
@Override
public CompletableFuture<List<ProductDTO>> dashboard( ) throws GeneralException {

    List<Product> products = newArrayList();

    /*....
    ....*/

    //I want this exception when calling CompletableFuture#get()
    if ( products.isEmpty() ) {
        throw new GeneralException( "user.not-has.product-message",
                "user.not-has.product-title" );
    }

    return CompletableFuture
            .completedFuture( ...) );
}
```

And `GeneralException` is defined like this:

```
public class GeneralException extends RuntimeException {...}
```

The problem is, when `GeneralException` is thrown, when I call the `CompletableFuture#get()` to get my data or the exception, I have a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` and not my custom `GeneralException`. Spring doc claims this:

> When an `@Async` method has a `Future`-typed return value, it is easy to
>   manage an exception that was thrown during the method execution, as
>   this exception is thrown when calling `get` on the `Future` result.

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks a lot

**EDIT:** 
This is the client code:

```
public static <T> T retrieveDataFromCompletableFuture( @NotNull CompletableFuture<T> futureData ) {
    T data = null;
    try {
        data = futureData.get();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        log.error( "Can't get data ", e );
    }
    return data;
}
```

And the exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.app.exceptions.GeneralException: user.not-has.product-message
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
.....
Caused by: org.app.exceptions.GeneralException: user.not-has.product-message
```

Why do I still have `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to not throw the exception, but complete feature with the exception

```
@Async
@Override
public CompletableFuture<List<ProductDTO>> dashboard( ) throws GeneralException {

    List<Product> products = newArrayList();

    /*....
    ....*/

    //I want this exception when calling CompletableFuture#get()
    if ( products.isEmpty() ) {
        CompletableFuture<List<ProductDTO>> result = new CompletableFeature<>();
        result.completeExceptionally(new GeneralException("user.not-has.product-message", 
            "user.not-has.product-title"
        );
        return result;
    }

    return CompletableFuture
        .completedFuture( ...) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that tomorrow morning, but do I need to add a return in the if statement or the `completeExceptionally()` will stop the execution?

Comment: you are absolutely right. I missed it. thank you! i will edit the answer

Comment: Thanks for you edit. After trying your suggestion, I still have the `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException` thrown (see the EDIT). To have my custom exception I need to throw it again in the client code by calling a `throw e.getCause()`. It's not really elegant I think.

Comment: Just for fun, could you please remove `@Async` annotation and catch the exception?